# How did the "S" quincy heal his eardrums?

Tags: bleach

The "S" quincy has the special ability to fully recover from damage after hearing the cheers of his followers.

However, how did he recover from his wounds after destroying his eardrums in his fight with the Captain of the 3rd Division?

Answer (score 1):

He receives the benefits of the cheering even though he could not hear the cheers of James as seen in [this page](http://www.mangapanda.com/bleach/562/7), [this page](http://www.mangapanda.com/bleach/562/8), and [this page](http://www.mangapanda.com/bleach/562/9).

Answer (score 1):

According to [Bleach Wiki](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Mask_De_Masculine#cite_note-38), Superstar's ability:

> The Superstar (英雄 (ザ・スーパースター), Eiyū (Za Sūpāsutā); Japanese for
>   "Hero"): Mask gains a considerable amount of zeal, stamina, and
>   strength when he has at least one other person cheering him on, enough
>   to send two captain-level Shinigami flying with a single strike.
>   He grows durable enough to become resistant to a repeated direct
>   attack from Kensei's Bankai. The power also allows him to
>   regenerate from damage, with James's cheers healing his damaged
>   eardrums.

It's indeed strange, as he could not listen to James cheering, but as you can see it's never mentioned the word "hear" or "listen".

So we can assume that he don't need to listen to the cheers. James only had be there, cheering, that's enough to active his ability.